# 7805 vs. 78L05 voltage regulators

Tags: voltage-regulator, kits

I ordered a [kit](http://bleeplabs.com/thingamagoop2/) that is missing its 78L05.  Can I substitute a 7805, or would I need to also adjust the cap values?  Here is the entire [schematic](http://bleeplabs.com/thing2/thingamagoop2%20sch.png).

Here is the voltage regulation portion of the schematic:

[image]

I have emailed Bleep Labs, but I thought this forum might be faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to substitute a 7805 for the 78L05 if you are willing to do a little kludging mechanically.  The L version is physically smaller and can dissipate less power and may be rated for less current.  If this is just a one-off, go ahead and solder on a 7805 in a TO-220 package onto the pads intended for the 78L05.

By the way, that must be a very old design.  10 nF is rather skimpy for the the input and output caps.  Nowadays you can easily put a small 10 µF cap on the output, and at least a 1 µF on the input depending on what the input voltage is.

Comment: I guess they are 100nF capacitors and there is a typo.

Comment: Thank you, Olin.  I _am_ worried about the larger package -- I started placing things last night and could barely insert the electrolytic caps' legs.  :\

Comment: @abdullahkahraman:  that wouldn't surprise me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

The 78L05 data sheet recommends a 330 nF on the input and a 10 nF on the output.

For the 7805 a 330 nF is recommended on the input and a 100 nF on the output.

Ceramics would be suitable.